# How to throw exceptions from outbound-gateway to sender

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-integration, outbound

I have been searching through Internet and trying many different ways, but I could not make it works.

What I want is to catch exceptions thrown from the outbound side, for example some validations, which should return an Exception to the sender whe they are not succesfully passed. I do not know if it is possible without using a DirectChannel to send requests from the server.

I hope someone can help me.

In the code below I show you my SI configuration, where filter with the SPEL expression, "checkRemoteOutputHeaders", throws an Exception when executes.

```
<int:channel id="requestChannelSb">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="timeStampCalllogger" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<task:executor id="threadPoolTaskExecutor" pool-size="10" queue-capacity="100" rejection-policy="DISCARD_OLDEST" />

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor">
    <constructor-arg name="executor" ref="threadPoolTaskExecutor"/>
    <constructor-arg name="errorHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler">
            <property name="defaultErrorChannel" ref="errorChannel"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<int:channel id="gatewayChannelSb">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="taskExecutor" failover="false"/>

    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="timeStampInitlogger" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="responseChannelSb">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="timeStampEndlogger" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="errorChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="errorlogger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>


<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannelSb"
    url="{urlVar}" http-method="POST"
    extract-request-payload="true"
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
    charset="UTF-8"
    header-mapper="headerMapper"
    reply-channel="responseChannelSb"
    request-timeout="60000">

    <int-http:uri-variable name="urlVar" expression="T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Utils).getUrl(headers)" />

</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int:chain input-channel="responseChannelSb">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="#{T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Constantes$HEADERS).BEAN}" expression="headers[T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Constantes$HEADERS).BEAN]"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int:transformer ref="customJsonToObjectTransformer"/>
</int:chain>


<int:chain id="chain" input-channel="gatewayChannelSb" output-channel="requestChannelSb">

    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:error-channel ref="errorChannel" overwrite="true"/>
        <int:header name="#{T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Constantes$HEADERS).REQUEST_ID}" expression="headers[T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Constantes$HEADERS).ID].toString()"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:filter expression="T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Utils).checkRemoteOutputHeaders(headers)" discard-channel="errorChannel" />

    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="#{T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Constantes$HEADERS).CONTENT_TYPE}" value="text/x-json" />
        <int:header name="#{T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Constantes$HEADERS).ACCEPT}" value="text/x-json" />
        <int:header name="#{T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Constantes$HEADERS).BEAN}" expression="T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Utils).getPayloadCanonicalClassName(payload)" />
        <int:header name="#{T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Constantes$HEADERS).SECURITY_USER}" expression="T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Utils).getSecurityUser()"/>
        <int:header name="#{T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Constantes$HEADERS).TARGET}" expression="T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Utils).getTargetUrl()"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:object-to-json-transformer object-mapper="jsonObjectMapper"/>
</int:chain>



<!-- Logging channels -->

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="timeStampInitlogger" level="INFO" expression="'Inicio de la peticion: '.concat(T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Utils).getRequestInfoTrace(headers))"/>
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="timeStampCalllogger" level="INFO" expression="'Envio de la peticion: '.concat(T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Utils).getRequestInfoTrace(headers))"/>
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="timeStampEndlogger" level="INFO" expression="'Final de la peticion: '.concat(T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Utils).getRequestInfoTrace(headers))"/>
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="destinationCalllogger" level="INFO" expression="'Destino peticion: '.concat(headers[T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Constantes$HEADERS).SUBSYSTEM])"/>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="errorlogger" level="ERROR" expression="'ERROR: '.concat(T(gnf.servicebroker.util.Utils).getRequestInfoTrace(headers))"/>

<!-- End Logging channels -->


<int:chain input-channel="errorChannel" output-channel="responseChannelSb">
    <int:transformer ref="messageHandlingExceptionTransformer"/>
</int:chain>
```

In the following code I show you the transformer, "messageHandlingExceptionTransformer", which convert the MessaggingException to ServiceException (custom exception):

```
    @Transformer
public Message<ServiceException> transform(ErrorMessage message){

    LOGGER.debug("INIT - transform(message=" + message + ")");

    MessagingException messageException = (MessagingException) message.getPayload();

    ServiceException serviceEx = new ServiceException(messageException.getMessage(), messageException.getCause());

    Message<?> originalMsg = messageException.getFailedMessage();

    Message<ServiceException> transformedObj = MessageBuilder.withPayload(serviceEx).copyHeaders(originalMsg.getHeaders()).build();


    LOGGER.debug("END - transform=" + transformedObj);

    return transformedObj;
}
```

The other transformer "customJsonToObjectTransformer" just convert a String payload (JSON) to a Java object and returns it, but if the payload is not a String, for example an exception, it returns it directly.

Thans in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason why the caller did not receive the Exception thrown during the outbound lifecycle.

I was just a configuration problem, because in other XML file I had the gateway definition which indicates its error-channel which was the same than the one defined in the outbound configuration. So it produced a cyclic chain of calls, because in the outbound the ErrorMessage with the exception is managed in the errorChannel once and then again in the error-channel of the gateway, which was the same, so the petition enters again in the chain which manages the errorChannel and finally it fails without informing the caller.

```
<int:gateway id="gcccSearchServiceRequestByCodeServiceSb" 
    service-interface="gnf.servicebroker.gps.atencioncliente.atcomercializadora.servicerequest.service.GcccSearchServiceRequestByCodeServiceISb" 
    default-request-channel="gatewayChannelSb"
    error-channel="errorChannel">
    <int:method name="gcccSearchServiceRequestByIdSr">
        <int:header name="Method" value="gcccSearchServiceRequestByIdSr"/>
        <int:header name="Module" value="atencioncliente"/>
        <int:header name="Service" value="gnf.servicebroker.gps.atencioncliente.atcomercializadora.servicerequest.service.GcccSearchServiceRequestByCodeServiceISb"/>
        <int:header name="SubSystem" value="atec-web"/>
    </int:method>
</int:gateway>
```

Notice the **error-channel** attribute, which has the same value than the error channel definend in the outbound configuration, so removing this attribute the caller can catch the exceptions:

```
<int:gateway id="gcccSearchServiceRequestByCodeServiceSb" 
    service-interface="gnf.servicebroker.gps.atencioncliente.atcomercializadora.servicerequest.service.GcccSearchServiceRequestByCodeServiceISb" 
    default-request-channel="gatewayChannelSb">
    <int:method name="gcccSearchServiceRequestByIdSr">
        <int:header name="Method" value="gcccSearchServiceRequestByIdSr"/>
        <int:header name="Module" value="atencioncliente"/>
        <int:header name="Service" value="gnf.servicebroker.gps.atencioncliente.atcomercializadora.servicerequest.service.GcccSearchServiceRequestByCodeServiceISb"/>
        <int:header name="SubSystem" value="atec-web"/>
    </int:method>
</int:gateway>
```

I hope it helps to anyone.

Thank you!!!